# Sitecore XA (SXA) + Multilist with Search + Page List

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa, sitecore9

Using OOTB SXA, I am trying to render selected items from Multilist with Search.

The data renders, but with everything nested in a single `<li>` broken into `<div>`'s

Among other things, I've tried using and Item Query (re: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/04/sitecore-sxa-pagelist-item-query.html), but didn't have any success.

**Q:** What is the correct way to render my items as individual `<li>`'s?

---

Current Results displayed:

[image]

```
<main>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="component page-list col-12">
            <div class="component-content">
                <ul class="items">
                    <li class="item">
                        <div class="field-first-name">Stephen</div>
                        <div class="field-last-name">King</div>
                        <div class="field-first-name">Gregory</div>
                        <div class="field-last-name">Mertens</div>
                        <div class="field-first-name">Penny</div>
                        <div class="field-last-name">Mertens</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

---

Multi Select List Data Source:

[image]

---

List Item:

[image]

---

Control Properties:

[image]

---

Rendering Variant

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: the reason you see <div> tags for each field that's rendered in your <li> is because the variant field definition is telling it to render a <div>.. Have you tried leaving the Tag field empty on the First Name and Last Name VariantField